# how to Upload a file using axios without using formdata api?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, axios

I have to upload a file to an api that expects content type to be 'image/jpeg'.
Using formData seems to set the content-type as 'multipart-formdata'. How do I get around this? Can I upload the file without using formData?